# Java Regular Expression Match on +/-/*/%

Tags: java, regex

So I have a string I would like to parse and I can not get my regular expression to work. I am using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp as my regular expression guide.

I would like my regular expression to match on any of the following symbols.

```
+ - * % /
```

My code as follows. Input String: `D[1]+D[0]`. Should print true...*but* prints false.

```
String tmp = "D[1]+D[0]";
if(tmp.matches("[\\+\\-\\*\\/\\%]"))
    System.out.println("true");
else
    System.out.println("false");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using just 1 backslash to escape the characters.

Comment: @Serdalis The java compiler requires \ to be escaped. A single backslash only works for the following sequences `\b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\`

Comment: The first thing to do is realise that **Java is not Javascript!** So a web reference for Javascript is not necessarily going to be that much use for Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html should be your first point of call for reference purposes.

Comment: Please use [Pattern.quote(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I do not think Pattern.quote is what I am looking for. Input params do not take in regular expression and no way to pass my tmp variable.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for pointing that out. Although regular expression is regular expression, not much difference between the one from Mozilla and Sun. However, reading up on the latest java docs is best. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam - At least using `Pattern.quote` you are getting Regex escaping out of your face. This just leaves you with Java escaping which is much more succinct.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon make sense. Def. going to add `Patter.quote` to my tool belt :)

Comment: Be warned that `Pattern.quote` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It quotes the string using \Q and \E, so it will treat the entire string as a literal via regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `matches` wants the entire string to be matched, not just any part of it.

You do not need to escape characters inside square brackets.

```
String str = "D[1]+D[0]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-/*]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: " + m.group());
}
```

Comment: thanks. This is what I was looking for. I did not know about Matcher. This is what I was looking for! I also like how you can pass in params to `group`. Also seems like `.find()` would be good to use when having more complex `str` in your Pattern.

Comment: @Adam Calling `find` repeatedly lets you find the next occurrence of the regexp. You need to use parentheses to capture multiple groups. See regexp documents for more info on this, the library is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

`matches()` must match the entire input, but all you need do is add `.*` to each end:

```
if (tmp.matches(".*[-+*/%].*"))
```

Note: Characters between `[]` don't need escaping *if* the hyphen is first or last.